# Fastest way to solve the following system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$−y +z −3t = 0$

$3x +4y +6z −6t = 0$

$x −y +2z −2t = 0$

What is the fastest method? I usually use substitution but it takes time in higher dimensions. I already know that the rank of the matrix is $3$.

Comment: There is no unique solution to this equation . You have three equations and four variables.

Comment: Do you know about [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

Comment: Also, $\text{Equation 2} - 3 \times \text{Equation 3}$ gives $7y = 0$

Comment: Yes, I know that the system has infinite solutions. But I need the fastest way to find them

Comment: General solutions/approaches are rarely the fastest. You need to look at particular features of the equation you have been given. In this case, it is not hard to see that $y=0$ and after that it is easy.

Comment: Thanks but how do you see that y is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting your system in the form
$$x-y+2z-2t=0$$
$$3x+4y+6z-6t=0$$
$$-y+z-3t=0$$
Multiplying the first equation by $-3$ and adding to the second one we get
$$7y=0$$
Multiplying  the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the third we obtain
$$-z-t=0$$
Can you finish?

Comment: No, You should get $y=0$, not $z=0$.

Comment: From $7z=0$ you will get $z=0$ and then $$0-t=0$$ you will get $t=0$

Comment: True. But your first step was wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong

Comment: If you add $3y$ to $4y$ you get $7y$ not $7z$!

Comment: Sorry, this was only a typo by me! Just corrected!

Comment: But your conclusion that $z=-t$ now does not follow. It should be $z=3t$.

Comment: You have to add $$-x+y-2z+2t=0$$ and $$-y+z-3t=0$$ this gives $$-x-z-t=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can solve $x,y,z$ in terms of $t$.

Subtract $3$ times the third equation from the second one and you get $y=0$

Plug in the first one and you get $z=3t$

Plug in the third equation and you get $x=-4t$

Thus  your solution is $$(x,y,z)= t(-4,0,3)$$